# How to create a table of elements with different content

Tags: actionscript-3

How do i create a 3x3 table (in tabular form) and every cell has a different image.
But i want to create the cell and then in it add the picture of the icon, not make the icon an movieClip and directly adding it after that.

I`m trying to have 3 rows :

**1st** row will be Time1 ,Time2 ,Time3.

**2nd** row Turbo1 ,Turbo2 ,Turbo3

**3rd** row will be something like Speed1, Speed2, Speed3 .

Something like the picture below.

(in blue are the names of the bitmaps/movieClips/names of the pictures I am using for every icon)[image]

i was thinking of doing it like this

```
private var testArr:Array = new Array();

public function MainClass()
{
  for(var i:int=0; i<3; i++) 
  {
    testArr[i]= new Array();
    for(var j:int = 0 ; j<3 ; j++)
      {
          testArr[i][j] = new IconClass();
          this.addChild(testArr[i][j]);
        testArr[i][j].x=testArr[i][j].width*j + j*10;
        testArr[i][j].y=testArr[i][j].height*i + i*10;
        testArr[i][j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, somethingFancy );
   }
}
```

}

and on **new IconClass();** i would pass the image that it needs to have. But! how would it be done ??

Comment: So, is `IconClass` a real Class so you can pass same parameter into it, or `IconClass` just mean the general icon class name?

Comment: well if it is a Class( i think this is the better way) then i would have to put **new IconClass(i,j);**
and in it ill change the image depending on the **i** and **j** values ? but still i cant figure out how

Comment: Why not use a `Class Dictionary` or `Array`? You can put `Class` into an `Array` or `Dictionary`.

Comment: i havent used _Dictionary_ ever. So are you telling me to put the images in the Array and then to get them from it ? cause i dont quite get what you are telling me

Comment: Yes, you can put `Class` to an Array, and new it one by one.

Comment: yet is there a more not that noob way to push items in the array. cause what i see i have to use 9 times **myPictureArray.push(image1)** to image9

Comment: Hi there, how you store your images into an array really depends more on how you are loading (if at all). To move this along a bit faster please join this stackoverflow chat:

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44499/how-to-create-a-table-of-elements-with-different-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as discussed there are a couple of useful designs. For handling the different images for different states I would create an `Icon` class that is a display object that handles what images to load for the different states.

That would look something like:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class icon extends Sprite
    {
        private var _images:Vector.<Object>;
        public var isEnabled:Boolean;

        public function icon() {
            _images = new Vector.<Object>();
        }

        //in this functions all the images you need for different states
        private function addImage( state:String, bitmap:Bitmap ):void {
            _images.push( { state:state, image:bitmap } );
        }

        //change the image of the sprite, based on the state ( i.e. - mouseOver, mouseOut )
        public function changeState( state:String ):void {
            var i:int;
            state = isActive ? "enabled" + state : "disabled" + state;

            for ( ; i < _images.length; i++ ) {
                if ( _images[i].state == state ) {
                    updateImage( _images[i].image );
                }
            }
        }

        private function updateImage( bitmap:Bitmap ):void {
            //do image changing here to new bitmap
        }
    }
}
```

And what is happening here is the `icon` class will have a vector of objects that associate the correct bitmap to the correct state. Now how that would be setup in your table might look something like this:

```
private var _iconList:Vector.<icon>;

public function MainClass():void  {   
        createSprites();
        _iconList = new Vector.<icon>();

        var rows    :int = 3, 
        columns     :int = 3, 
        startX      :int = 0, //set to some x coordinate
        startY      :int = 0, //set to some y coordinate
        padding     :int = 5, 
        i           :int, 
        j           :int,
        currentIndex:int;

        for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
            for ( j = 0; j < columns; j++ ) {
                _iconList[currentIndex].x = startX + i * ( _iconList[currentIndex].width + padding );
                _iconList[currentIndex].y = startY + j * ( _iconList[currentIndex].height + padding );
                _iconList[currentIndex].addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver );
                _iconList[currentIndex].addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut );
                addChild( _iconList[currentIndex] );
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    private function createIcons():void {
        var i:int;
        for ( ; i < 9; i++ ) {
            var ic:icon = new icon();
            ic.addImage( "disabledMouseOver", "yourImageGetter()" ); //you're using a getAtlas() to a bitmap
            ic.addImage( "disabledMouseOut", "yourImageGetter()" );
            ic.addImage( "enabledMouseOver", "yourImageGetter()" );
            ic.addImage( "enabledMouseOut", "yourImageGetter()" );
            _iconList.push( ic );
        }
    }

    private function onMouseOver( e:MouseEvent ):void {
        var ic:icon = e.target as icon;
        ic.changeState( "MouseOver" );
    }

    private function onMouseOut( e:MouseEvent ):void {
        var ic:icon = e.target as icon;
        ic.changeState( "MouseOut" );
    }
```

So what's happening here:

- We create an icon class that has storage for the different bitmap images and different states to associate them with
- In our main class, we do `createIcons()` which makes new `icons` and adds the different images for the different states
- Then we create our table with the list of icons in `_iconList` and add the mouse event listeners to each of them.
- The listeners `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` call the targeted icon `changeState()` which will then handle the correct image to switch between.

Edit:

- The `isEnabled` boolean is going to be used at your discretion ( as discussed in chat ) from another view to control icons that are enabled for the user and which `MOUSE_OVER` and `MOUSE_OUT` states to use.

Comment: Hey, it might be a little late but I`m getting an error and dont know how to solve/remove it.It is  **1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type ** regarding the **ic.addImage( "enabledMouseOut", "yourImageGetter()" );**.I was thinking of sending the path to the **icon()** class as a string and there get it from the source to rather the image itself, but then i noticed that the path to the images are only 4 in the creteIcons() function _/in the main class/_ and it seems like i need 36(3 rows x 3 images x 4 states of the mouse).I tried to contact but there is no PM in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
private var iconArr:Array = new Array();
private var testArr:Array = new Array();

public function MainClass()
{
    iconArr.push(

    [
    "time1",
    "time2",
    "time3"
    ],

    [
    "turbo1",
    "turbo2",
    "turbo3"
    ],

    [
    "speed1",
    "speed2",
    "speed3"
    ]

    );
    for(var i:int=0; i<3; i++) 
    {
        testArr[i]= new Array();
        for(var j:int = 0 ; j<3 ; j++)
        {
            //pass in a string, the icon will change depending on that string
            testArr[i][j] = new IconClass(iconArr[i][j]);

            this.addChild(testArr[i][j]);
            testArr[i][j].x=testArr[i][j].width*j + j*10;
            testArr[i][j].y=testArr[i][j].height*i + i*10;
            testArr[i][j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, somethingFancy );
        }
    }
}
```

May not fit your needs, in which case you should edit it.